# Replacing ereg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ereg

I have some legacy code I'm trying to update to run on PHP 5.4:

```
$row['subject'] = ereg_replace('[\]', '', $row['subject']);
```

I know I have to replace this with preg_replace, but since I've never used ereg, I'm not sure what this actually does.

Is the equivalent:

```
preg_replace('/[\\]/'...
```

or

```
preg_replace('/\[\\\]/'...
```

Can anyone shine a light on what the correct replacement should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted replaces the backslashes with nothing and it doesn't match the square brackets; they are used to create a character range that contains only the backslash character and are completely useless on your `regex`.

The equivalent `preg_replace()` statement is:

```
$row['subject'] = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $row['subject']);
```

The `regex` is `/\\/`. Using a single backslash (`\`) produces an error; the backslash is an escape character in `regex`, it escapes the `/` making it be interpreted literally and not as the delimiter. The two extra backslashes are needed because the backslash is also an escape character in `PHP` and it needs to be escaped too.

I guess this was the reason the original coder enclosed the backslash into a range, to circumvent the need for escaping and double escaping.

Using the same trick you can write it with `preg_replace()` as:

```
$row['subject'] = preg_replace('/[\]/', '', $row['subject']);
```

A single backslash is enough. In the `regex` [the backslash escapes are not allowed in character ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended). And in PHP single-quoted strings, the backslash needs to be escaped only if it is the last character from the string.

*(I know, the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) teaches us to double all the backslashes, but, on the other hand, it says that a backslash that does not precede an apostrophe or another backslash in single-quoted strings is interpreted literally.)*

Back to the `regex`, there is a better (faster, cleaner) way to rewrite the above call to `ereg_replace()`: **do not** use `regex` at all. Because all it does is to match (and replace) the backslashes, you don't need to use `regex`. A simple `str_replace()` is enough:

```
$row['subject'] = str_replace('\\', '', $row['subject']);
```

Comment: There's also route three, http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php. `echo stripslashes('test\\wolf\\cow');`.